# What's the idiomatic way of consuming read-only struct's fields many times in the same function?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm just starting with Rust and since I'm a person who learns by doing I would like to fully understand the idiomatic way of solving cases like this in Rust.

Many replies I got in chat are all the same: "clone!".

I don't want to `clone()`, I'm here to learn better ways otherwise I'll go back to using Golang or Javascript.

Plus I'm afraid of cloning because I don't wanna allocate many times the same data (`Config`) in this case.

Even if I work with many workers (this is the case with actix-web) I wanna use references to that struct, not clone each time allocating many times the same data. Am I wrong?

In the simple below code as you can see I'm passing the struct `Config` by value to a function. In that function I need to refer to some fields of that struct and I'm havng serious troubles understanding how to do.

- main.rs:

```rust
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};
use std::net::SocketAddr;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let config = new_config();
    start(config).await.unwrap();
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Config { // never changes during the app life, it's a read only once created at runtime
    pub app_name: String,
    pub port: String,
}

fn new_config() -> Config {
    Config {
        app_name: String::from("APP_NAME"),
        port: String::from("1234"),
    }
}

pub struct AppState {
    pub config: Config,
}

async fn hello() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok()
}

async fn start(config: Config) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    println!("{}", config.app_name); //I'm using it the first time here

    let server = HttpServer::new(move || { // I'm moving it here
        App::new()
            .app_data(web::Data::new(AppState { config })) // here I get an error: cannot move out of `config`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure. move occurs because `config` has type `Config`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait rustc E0507
            .route(&config.app_name, web::get().to(hello))
    });

    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], config.port.parse::<u16>().unwrap())); // here another error: borrow of moved value: `config`. borrow occurs due to deref coercion to `str` rustc E0382

    server.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?.run().await
}
```

Can you help me understand **what's the idiomatic way of doing this with Rust?**

Comment: Note that a `.clone()` does not necessarily allocate, nor is it expensive for all types. For example, "cloning" a `u8` is a no-op, it just gives you the same number. Also, "cloning" an `Arc` just  bumps the reference count and gives you the same pointer. Answers that instruct you to use `Arc` are the correct ones, because they allow you to retain references to `Config` after having shipped it off to other parts of code that expect an owned value. That **is** how this situation is idiomatically handled in Rust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, since you can't guarantee that the `Config` value will live long enough, what you probably want is `Arc<Config>` which communicates thread-safe shared ownership of the value. You can clone the `Arc` which only duplicates the handle; there is still only one `Config` instance.  For example:

```
pub struct AppState {
    pub config: Arc<Config>,
}

async fn start(config: Config) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    // Move the config into an Arc.
    let config = Arc::new(config);
    println!("{}", config.app_name);

    // Get a second Arc for the same Config; this second Arc will be moved
    // into the closure.
    let config2 = Arc::clone(&config);

    let server = HttpServer::new(move || {
        // We clone the handle to create the AppState because we can't move
        // out of a captured variable in an Fn closure.
        App::new()
            .app_data(web::Data::new(AppState { config: Arc::clone(&config2) }))
            .route(&config2.app_name, web::get().to(hello))
    });

    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], config.port.parse::<u16>().unwrap()));

    server.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?.run().await
}
```

Alternatively, you can [leak a box](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak), which gives you a `'static` reference.  This is suitable for data that will live for the entire duration of the program **as long as it's not important that the data be cleanly dropped.** (This is fine for `String` values; the OS will clean up the allocations when the program terminates.)

```
pub struct AppState {
    pub config: &'static Config,
}

async fn start(config: Config) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    // Move the config into a box, then leak it.
    let config = Box::leak(Box::new(config));
    println!("{}", config.app_name);

    let server = HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .app_data(web::Data::new(AppState { config }))
            .route(&config.app_name, web::get().to(hello))
    });

    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], config.port.parse::<u16>().unwrap()));

    server.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?.run().await
}
```

The `Arc` approach is cleaner, while the leaked-box approach is easier to implement.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don’t understand why too many config alloc for the Arc approach. Can you better explain, please?

Comment: What do you mean by "why too many config alloc"? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry. I mean, do we need all those `Arc::clone(&config)`? Visually it's not a pretty sight.

Comment: I'm trying your code @cdhowie. Thanks again. I'm having issue with the `config` in line: `let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], config.port.parse::<u16>().unwrap()));`. The error is: `borrow of moved value: "config"; borrow occurs due to deref coercion to "common::config::Config" rustc E0382`.

Comment: It works. I was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @FredHors Yes, you need the `Arc::clone()` calls. This creates a new `Arc` handle to the _same_ `Config` value (the `Config` is _not_ cloned). This allows us to move one `Arc` handle into the closure and keep the other one around to access the port later.